# How to put programmatically created Horizontally Scrolling view with XML created Layout in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, android-layoutparams

In my app a user can select multiple images from gallery then he can view it within the app.

I have three buttons within a [Relative Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YnnH.jpg)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.codenemesis.multipleimg.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="imageSelector"

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="up"
    android:text="Upload"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="viewclick"
    android:text="View Images" />
```

To show the images I programmatically created `ImageView` array within `HorizontalScrollView` set to `WRAP_CONTENT` but the problem is when I click on view button `HorizontalScrollView` span over the whole screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlJNY.jpg).
I want to show `HorizontalScrollView` below view button. How can I do it?

Here is how I created **HorizontalScrollView**

```
  HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
                   LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams prams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   linearLayout.setLayoutParams(prams);
                   linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


                   horizontalScrollView.addView(linearLayout);
                   // mArrayUri is the arraylist of images selected from gallery
                   int b = mArrayUri.size();
                   int c = 0;

                   ImageView[] imageViews = new ImageView[mArrayUri.size()];
                   while (c < mArrayUri.size()) {
                       imageViews[c] = new ImageView(this);
                       imageViews[c].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                       imageViews[c].setPadding(10,0,10,0);
                       imageViews[c].setImageURI(mArrayUri.get(c));
                       linearLayout.addView(imageViews[c]);
                       c++;
                       // Set context view
                       setContentView(horizontalScrollView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your xml file should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.myapplication.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="select images"
    android:onClick="imageSelector"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="up"
    android:text="Upload"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="viewclick"
    android:text="View Images" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code in you java file should be like this

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relativeLayout=findViewById(R.id.parent_panel);
}
public void imageSelector(View view)
{
}
public void up(View view)
{
}
public void viewclick(View view)
{
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView =
    new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams prams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(prams);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    horizontalScrollView.addView(linearLayout);
    // mArrayUri is the arraylist of images selected from gallery
    int b = mArrayUri.size();
    int c = 0;
    ImageView[] imageViews = new ImageView[mArrayUri.size()];
    while (c < mArrayUri.size()) {
        imageViews[c] = new ImageView(this);
        imageViews[c].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imageViews[c].setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        imageViews[c].setImageURI(mArrayUri.get(c));
        linearLayout.addView(imageViews[c]);
        c++;
    }
    relativeLayout.addView(horizontalScrollView);
}
```

}

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Hey Farhan, Thanks for the help but I'm still getting this error, **"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4454)"** error points to `relativeLayout.addView(horizontalScrollView`

Comment: Hey Farhan, Thanks for the help, after your solution i was still getting this error, **"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4454)"** error points to `relativeLayout.addView(horizontalScrollView`. so i removed line  `setContentView(horizontalScrollView);` and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: remove this line
setContentView(horizontalScrollView);